# Vertical Align Inline-Block With Height 100%

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

First I'll list my code and the link to JSFiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            Here is the content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
body,html{height:100%;}
#wrapper{
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
#container {
    display: inline-block ;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#content
{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/b4ZBg/

(Newer one with more content for vertical center testing)

http://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/sDWxN/11/

What I'm trying to do is ***vertically center*** the blue highlighted DIV in the center of the red div.  Is there a way to do this **using inline-block and not table-cells**?

**The height of the containing div also HAS to be 100% not a set pixel amount.**

**The content will also be variable height**

I am trying to avoid table-cell display because of browser bugs, but if it's the only option I would like to know that also.  Any solution to this issue would be appreciative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The art of vertical centring with inline-block is to understand that the inline-level elements are centred in their line-box. So you need to make the line-height match the height of the containing box.

The line-height is determined by a combination of the line-height setting of the containing block and the content of the line.

However the line-height of the containing box cannot be set in terms of a percentage of the height of the containing box, so that provides no solution.

Instead, we can create some content on the same line as the content we want to align that's the height of the containing block using

```
#container:before {
    display:inline-block;
    content: '';
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

which will force the line height be tall enough to contain that content.

The other thing necessary is to note that `vertical-align` is applied to the boxes being aligned, rather than the containing box.

The result is http://jsfiddle.net/9j95x/

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to this.  This is a very good method, very clever.  Reminds me of the clearfix trick for floats.

Comment: This won't work with lots of content however, so I have to revoke the answer.  Put lots of content in the inline-block div and it will break the centering.

Comment: Well, the answer above meets the requirements laid out in your question. The vertical centring breaks when the text fills a complete line because there's not enough horizontal space for the content box, the pseudo-element box and the space between them. That's easily fixable by eliminating that space width (which is between the `<div id="container">` and `<div id="content">` tags) by using one of several of the methods described in http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/. E.g. adding `margin-left:-0.27em;` to the pseudo-element will do the trick.

Comment: Never mind your code did work, I was trying to respond to someone else's answer not yours.  Your solution works great for what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```css
top: 50%;
position: relative;
```

on `#content`, like so:

```css
#content
{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/sDWxN/9/

Comment: Interesting Idea, I will give this a try in my application.  I will have to see if this has any issues since it's using relative positioning but hopefully not.

Comment: Note that the blue div is actually hanging BELOW the midpoint, so if it needs to be perfectly in the vertical center, you'll need to offset the height of the content by setting it to be a particular height and setting a negative margin. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/WmstL/

Comment: The problem with this method is it will center to the top left of the blue div.  When I edit my fiddle to put more text you will see that it does not center correctly.

Comment: Just saw your message, one sec, let me look at JSFiddle.

Comment: You still need to know the height of the content to solve that problem though.  So it doesn't solve my issue, the height is always unknown for the content.  Thank you for the idea though so far.

Comment: In that case, I frequently use jQuery to detect the height of the center div and set the margin to `that / 2`

Comment: His technique is the best for this case. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick response: http://jsfiddle.net/H9nHh/

Basically use:
`display:table;` for #container

and `display:table-cell;` for #content. I then created another div with a class for x to style it to your needs.

Comment: You might want to see this page for more details on options for vertical alignment: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: Nice, this method seems to work pretty well.  It does use table-cell but I think it's the only way and might be the only answer.  It seems to be the only thing that honors vertical-align:middle correctly.

Comment: I definitely disagree with the use of `display: table` for this purpose. Recommend that you use techniques like the one @r3mus posted.

Comment: What is your specific reason for disagreeing? Solution by @r3mus does not honour the size of the actual content.

Comment: @AhmedSagarwala If we use `display: table;` (table-cell, table-row) it would be better to use tables (that the right should be used for tabular data, not layouts). `display: table;` is an easy path, but it is obscure. I believe that was not designed for this purpose. A better use would *css3-grid* ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid ) or `position: relative;` + `top:` + `margin-top:`. Note: this is just my opnion, need not consider it.

Comment: @AhmedSagarwala I found this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#tables-intro Not that you can not use, but can is followed by restrictions and is intended for the use of *tables* (apparently is designed to create elements like tables with XML tags).

Comment: @Guilheme: So it's more a semantics issue. In this case since the positioning is more important, `display:table` is the easiest way to achieve it. Using actual table tags adds a little more code in terms of HTML. The only other issue I can see with using this route is regarding browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=table